# Active Directory Last Name Change and SQL Windows Authentication Hundreds of Databases

Tags: sql-server, windows, active-directory

I have a user that has changed their last name. They access many different SQL databases across dozens of servers with Windows Authentication.

What is the best way to update their last name other than creating a new AD account and migrating them over to the new AD account?

Comment: In the SQL the AD-User is stored with it's SID so a namechange will work transparent for the SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Thank you [johannes krackowizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838837/johannes-krackowizer)  for your valuable suggestion. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members***

Even if you changed user last name, it won't affect SQL Server.

- While setting up login in SQL Server, you have to enter **username** and **domain of the account.**
- After that, it will go to Windows and grabs the **Security Identifier**(SID) of the account
- It stores both in the SQL Server
- So, when you change user's last name in Windows, the **SID** **will remain same.**
- When the user is logging to SQL Server, the SID will be passed from client to server that verifies against the database.

To know more about SIDs, find the link below:

[SQL Server Logins, Users and Security Identifiers (SIDs) (sqlshack.com)](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-logins-users-security-identifiers-sids/) by Simon Liew